# distinct with multiple columns and then group by one - rails, mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a dataset that gives the underlying output to the underlying query:

```
Analyze
  .where(some_conditions)
  .joins(category: [category_subs: :sub])
  .select('user_id, product_id, category_subs.sub_id as sub_id, is_successful, category_subs.level as level')
```

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
| user_id | product_id  | is_successful | sub_id | level       |
+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
| 3223    | 20441       | 1             | 56     | 14          |
| 3223    | 20441       | 1             | 72     | 22          |
| 3223    | 20441       | 1             | 20     | 22          |
| 3223    | 20443       | 1             | 20     | 14          |
| 3223    | 20443       | 1             | 20     | 22          |
| 3223    | 20443       | 1             | 25     | 6           |
| 3223    | 20443       | 1             | 7      | 22          |
| 3223    | 20444       | 1             | 20     | 14          |
| 3223    | 20444       | 1             | 20     | 22          |
| 3223    | 20444       | 1             | 25     | 6           |
| 3223    | 20444       | 1             | 7      | 22          |
| 3223    | 20445       | 0             | 20     | 14          |
| 3223    | 20445       | 0             | 20     | 22          |
| 3223    | 20445       | 0             | 25     | 6           |
| 3223    | 20445       | 0             | 7      | 22          |
| 3223    | 20448       | 1             | 20     | 14          |
| 3223    | 20448       | 1             | 20     | 22          |
| 3223    | 20448       | 1             | 25     | 6           |
| 3223    | 20448       | 1             | 7      | 22          |
| 3223    | 20449       | 1             | 20     | 14          |
| 3223    | 20449       | 1             | 4      | 2           |
| 3223    | 20449       | 1             | 24     | 14          |
+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
```

All i want from that data is success by sub category with ignoring the *level* attribute.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work as i expected:

```
Analyze
  .where(some_conditions)
  .joins(category: [category_subs: :sub])
  .group('sub_id')
  .select('user_id, product_id, category_subs.sub_id as sub_id, sum(is_successful=0)')
```

Output the output that did not give the result I wanted:

```
+--------+----------------------+
| sub_id | sum(is_successful=1) |
+--------+----------------------+
| 4      | 1                    |
| 7      | 3                    |
| 20     | 8                    |
| 24     | 1                    |
| 25     | 3                    |
| 56     | 1                    |
| 72     | 1                    |
+--------+----------------------+
```

Expected output should be:

```
+--------+----------------------+
| sub_id | sum(is_successful=1) |
+--------+----------------------+
| 4      | 1                    |
| 7      | 3                    |
| 20     | 5                    |
| 24     | 1                    |
| 25     | 3                    |
| 56     | 1                    |
| 72     | 1                    |
+--------+----------------------+
```

I can get the data in ruby way, but i need it in the *ActiveRecord::Relation* instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  t.sub_id,
  count(*)
from (
  select sub_id
  from f
  where is_successful = 1
  group by
    product_id,
    sub_id
  order by sub_id
) t
group by t.sub_id;
```

That might work. You can use ActiveRecord `from` to create the inner query for the from statement and then use that result in the outer select.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f25cc/2/0) a fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot (!) to mention the part that caused the problem, i've updated my question, added the "level" column.

Comment: Yes (for me). For example, the success value for sub 20 appears to be 8 (shown in last output table) but I want to ignore the *level* attribute, the success value should be 5.

Comment: in your sql fiddle, for *sub_id* 20, *SUM(is_successful)* value is 8. But if we ignore *level*, it should be 5, as i expected.

Comment: I want to show how many of this products in sub-category 20 is successfuly in some users hands, don't want to think about sub-categories' levels. If we make the data in the first table unique by user, product and sub id and ignore the level attr, we see that there are only 5 records with an sub_id 20.